# bug(Timepicker):bug(timepicker): Error when writing 12 in the text box reserved for hours, but when using the mousewheel Bug disappears

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

bug(timepicker): Error when writing 12 in the text box reserved for hours, but when using the mousewheel Bug disappears.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34269858/60980498-de9d7a00-a334-11e9-9aa6-6ea9560d03b1.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34269858/60980586-07257400-a335-11e9-94ff-feb81e7ff030.png

Comment: We’re seeing the issue (NG8 +ngx-bootstrap 5.1.1) where entering a 12, results in 00 in the hours box. Is that the same issue you are seeing?

Comment: yes i see the same issue. Do you have some solution?

Comment: Yes! Update to the latest version (5.1.3 I think).

Comment: yes everything is ok now... :)